# How can I delete everything until a pattern and everything after another pattern from a line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

In the following file:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut eu metus id lectus vestibulum ultrices. Maecenas rhoncus.

I want to delete everything before `consectetuer` and everything after `elit`.

My desired output:

```
consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The command can be `sed`. It can also be `perl`, or even pure bash.

Comment: @manuel If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'd use sed

```
sed 's/^.*\(consectetuer.*elit\).*$/\1/' file
```

Decoded the sed s/find/replace/ syntax:

- `s/^.*` -- substitute starting at the beginning of the line (`^`) followed by anything (`.*`) up to...
- `\(` - start a named block
- `consectetuer.*elit\.` - match the first word, everything (`.*`) up to the last word (in this case, including the trailing (escaped)dot) you want to match
- `\)` - end the named block
- match everything else (`.*`) to the end of the line (`$`)
- `/` - end the substitute find section
- `\1` - replace with the name block between the `\(` and the `\)` above
- `/` - end the replace

Comment: Good answer, but you don't need the `^` or `$` since sed will try and find the longest match.
Also you may have missed the dot after `elit`, you could insert `\.` if necessary.

Comment: @asoundmove Good catch on the trailing dot on "elit." -- you have quite a sharp eye!. I've updated my answer to include the the escaped dot in the pattern. Your also correct that the `^` and `$` aren't necessary -- I left them there for as the questioner noted (originally) that he was a bit of a beginner and this may be helpful in other contexts.

Comment: I've always copy-pasted sed solutions and hacked them to fit my needs but thanks to this answer I feel like I actually understand it now. Great answer

Comment: It seems not working for multiline files. If my "elit" word is on another line this seems not working well.

Answer (score 11):

If **every line** contains both start and end pattern then the easiest way to do this is with `grep`. Instead of *deleting* the beginning and ending of each line you can simply output the contents between both patterns. The `-o` option in GNU `grep` outputs only the matches:

```
grep -o 'consectetuer.*elit' file
```

Note: as mentioned, this only works if every line in the file can be parsed this way. Then again, that's 80% of all typical use-cases.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why this question title has been edited "**from file**" to "**from a line**" while the OP doesn't exclude the possibility across multiple lines even though the example seems to be one line only. Whatever, it might helpful to provide multiple lines solution here.

This works for cross-lines (*This answer works if `from1` and `to2` exist in the file.*):

```
from1=consectetuer; to2=elit; a="$(cat file)"; a="$(echo "${a#*"$from1"}")"; echo "$from1${a%%"$to2"*}$to2"
```

Examples:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$ cat file
1
abc consectetuer lsl

home
 
def elit dd
2 consectetuer ABC elit
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$ from1=consectetuer; to2=elit; a="$(cat file)"; a="$(echo "${a#*"$from1"}")"; echo "$from1${a%%"$to2"*}$to2"
consectetuer lsl

home
 
def elit
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$
```

reference: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: That's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Two for loops in AWK:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i == "consectetuer") beginning=i; if($i== "elit.") ending=i }; for (j=beginning;j<=ending;j++) printf $j" ";printf "\n"   }' file.txt 
consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

AWK's gsub:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^.*consectetuer/,"consectetuer"); gsub(/elit.*$/,"elit.");print}' file.txt
consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl way. This is essentially the same as [MikeV's `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243209/22222) answer:

```
perl -pe 's/.*(consectetuer.*elit).*./$1/' file
```

The `-p` means "print every line after applying the script given with `-e`". The `s/foo/bar/` is the substitution operator; it will replace `foo` with `bar`. The parentheses capture a pattern and let us use it in the replacement. The first captured pattern is `$1`, the second `$2` and so on.

So, the command will match everything up to `consectetuer` (`.*consectetuer`), then everything until `elit` (`.*elit`) and then everything else until the end of the line (`.*`) and will replace that with the captured pattern.