# How to delete everything (in every line) in a text file after a pattern of characters(including the pattern)?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Basically I need what the OP of this question got but didn't want. 
[How to delete everything after a certain pattern or a string in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/how-to-delete-everything-after-a-certain-pattern-or-a-string-in-a-file)

So I got the data like:

```
Something and something ........................... 23
Another one .......................................123
Somethingelse Inc. .................................243
```

So what I want is to delete the whole bunch of dots (and the numbers) after the space.

So far, I tried to use the OP's command there but it didn't quite work as I expected because it deletes everything after the first dot it encounters. Which means that the dot on the data of the sort Somethinelse Inc. is also deleted.

I tried to make the first (sed) answer from that question work by replacing the first .com with three dots and the second one with an empty space but I failed. This time everything after the first space is deleted or three dots left.

The second answer (ex -sc ...) worked like the OP wanted but it leaves some dots behind for me so I had no luck with it either.

I also tried to tweak the command from this answer but also failed at that. [How can I delete everything until a pattern and everything after another pattern from a line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243207/how-can-i-delete-everything-until-a-pattern-and-everything-after-another-pattern)

Comment: `sed 's/ \.\..*$//' /path/to/file` should work.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Why didn't you put it as an answer?

Comment: Because you said `sed` didn't work, I was expecting clarification as to what is didn't do properly.  I'll copy it into an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed 's/ \.\..*$//' /path/to/file` should work:

```
 \.\. - A space followed by two literal periods
.*    - One or characters of any type
$     - End of line
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
sed 's/\.\+ *[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]*$//g'
```

which means:

> one+to+many *(\+)* dots *(\.)* AND zero-to-many *(*)* spaces *( )* AND one+to+many *(\+)* [digits](https://superuser.com/a/513415/248836)*([[:digit:]])* AND just-in-case any *(*)* [whitespace](https://superuser.com/a/112837/248836) *([[:space:]])* AND End of this line ($)

Tested with (Note that i inserted "...234" in 2nd row, and trailing Tab/spaces):

```
Something and something ........................... 23<Tab>
An ...234 other one .......................................123<space>
Somethingelse Inc. .................................243<some spaces>
```

And the result:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ sed 's/\.\+ *[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]*$//g' sample.txt
Something and something 
An ...234 other one 
Somethingelse Inc. 
xb@dnxb:/tmp$
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it worked for me but it'd be nice if you could explain a bit what your answer does or what does it do differently.

Comment: @ShabanShneta updated.

Answer (score 0):

Another but unelegant solution could be:

`cat path/to/yourfile | sed -E "s/[\.]{2,}//g" | sed "s/[0-9]//g" > path/to/new_file`

where:

- `-E` Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions
- `[\.]{2,}` match a dot per two or more occurrences
- `[0-9]` match all digits
- `s/expr//g` means substitute matched `expr` with nothing as much as you can (g)