# How to delete everything before the occurrence of a regex pattern per line in a bash variable

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string

I've got a bash variable containing several lines of text, which includes IP addresses, and I need to remove 'everything' before the last IP address occurrence in the same line.

This:

```
43.12.40.53 refunds@example.uk
archery-666.foobar.com  66.77.11.44 data test@example
55.32.39.153    remix@example.com
5.113.30.37 dummy
89-109-22-006.static.example.com.br 89.109.22.6 hello@example.com
68.28.15.55 68.28.15.55 another
```

should be transform into:

```
43.12.40.53 refunds@example.uk
66.77.11.44 data test@example
55.32.39.153    remix@example.com
5.113.30.37 dummy
89.109.22.6 hello@example.com
68.28.15.55 another
```

Reading this post [How can I delete everything until a pattern and everything after another pattern from a line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243207/how-can-i-delete-everything-until-a-pattern-and-everything-after-another-pattern) I tried:

```
var=$(sed 's/^.*\(([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}\).*$/\1/' <<< "$var")
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. you're mixing BRE and ERE (for example `\(` versus `(` for the grouping)
2. your `.*` at the end needs to be inside the capture group if you want the result to include everything after the IP
3. the `^.*` at the beginning will greedily consume as many characters as it can - including all but one of the leading IP digits

Also, `.` doesn't need to be escaped inside `[]`  - although that doesn't break anything.

*I'm not sure the RIGHT way to deal with (3) in `sed` which (unlike `perl` say) doesn't have a non-greedy modifier. Adding a word-boundary anchor `\b` seems to work but feels fragile*

So either (BRE)

```
sed 's/^.*\(\b\([0-9]\{1,3\}[.]\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}.*$\)/\1/' <<< "$var"
```

or (ERE)

```
sed -E 's/^.*(\b([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}.*$)/\1/' <<< "$var"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly escaped the 1st parentheses, but not the second and not the `{}` which also need escaping. Also, you are matching everything to the end of the line (`.*$`) which isn't needed. Using your regex, this would do what you want:

```
$ sed 's/^.*\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}[\.]\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\1/' <<< "$var"
3.12.40.53 refunds@example.uk
6.77.11.44 data test@example
5.32.39.153    remix@example.com
5.113.30.37 dummy
9.109.22.6 hello@example.com
8.28.15.55 another
```

But this is still more complicated than necessary. For example, you don't need `[\.]`, a simple `\.` is enough. And you can use the `-E` flag to enable extended regular expressions and simplify your syntax to:

```
$ sed -E 's/^.*(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/\1/' <<< "$var"
3.12.40.53 refunds@example.uk
6.77.11.44 data test@example
5.32.39.153    remix@example.com
5.113.30.37 dummy
9.109.22.6 hello@example.com
8.28.15.55 another
```

However, [as steeldriver points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528821/22222), your leading `.*` might eat up more than you expect, so it would be safer to do the whole thing in perl instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^.*?(([\d]{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/\1/' <<< "$var"
43.12.40.53 refunds@example.uk
66.77.11.44 data test@example
55.32.39.153    remix@example.com
5.113.30.37 dummy
89.109.22.6 hello@example.com
68.28.15.55 68.28.15.55 another
```